# How can i know my smart contract , compilar version.I cant verify my contract properly

Tags: solidity, tokens

I want to know compilar version of my smart contract.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K5sM.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have mentioned the version as 0.4.9. The compiler will you this version to compile your code. If your system compiler version was lesser than 0.4.9 then it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to compile from 0.4.9 to 0.4.26.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;
```

^0.4.9 means "greater than 0.4.9 as 0.4.x"

And the latest version of 0.4.x is 0.4.26.